# Batch File: Syntax for IF ELSE

Tags: windows, batch-file, if-statement, syntax

I have an old Windows Server 2000 server in my environment that will not authenticate against server 2012 DCs. While we get this Server Upgraded I have to ensure that it always points at a Server 2008 R2 DC. The best solution I have come up with is a basic batch file that I will run every 5 mins (scheduled task) to first check the DC that it is pointing at and change it if necessary. I would also like to log these to a text file stamped with time and date

I know the script I want to write but have no idea of the Syntax to use for IF ELSE in a batch file. You can ignore what the command is actually doing I'm more interested in the syntax

I have attempted to write the script in JavaScript

```
if(nltest /server:ServerName123 /sc_query:branch === DCName01) 
{
\\I would like it to do nothing apart from write to a text file that it succeeded

    Print to a text file ("Ponting to DCNAME01 with time and date");
{
else
{
\\I would like it to run the following command to point the server to the correct DC

nltest /server:ServerName123 /sc_reset:branch\DCName01;
Print to a text file "("Changed to DCNAME01 with time and date");
}
```

thanks

Comment: What kept you from using Google? Instead of writing up all this you could just have searched...

Answer (score 1):

```
@echo off

rem set nltest query result  to variable
for /f "tokens=* delims=" %%# in ('nltest /server:ServerName123 /sc_query:branch') do (

    set "nlquery=%%#"
)


if "%nlquery%" equ "DCName01" (

    echo Ponting to DCNAME01 with time and date >some.file
) else (
   nltest /server:ServerName123 /sc_reset:branch\DCName01
   echo Changed to DCNAME01 with time and date >some.file   
)
```

**edit** - [using conditional execution](http://ss64.com/nt/syntax-conditional.html)

```
@echo off

nltest /server:ServerName123 /sc_query:branch | find /i "DCName01" 2>nul 1>nul && (
    echo Ponting to DCNAME01 with time and date >some.file
) || (
    nltest /server:ServerName123 /sc_reset:branch\DCName01
    echo Changed to DCNAME01 with time and date >some.file  
)
```

[More info.](http://ss64.com/nt/if.html)

Comment: Really appreciate this npocmaka. Its the start I needed. I'll let you know how I get on. Thanks again.

Comment: Very nearly got it working - just having issues with

Comment: Very nearly got it working - just having issues with - if %nlquery% equ "DCName01".  When I run the full command in CMD it returns 4 lines of results. How do I make the script search for just "DCNAme01" from the 4 lines of results. I have tried equ "(Star)DCNAME01(Star)" (I'm trying to use the start symbol but the editor changes the font to bold, I'm new to this forum :) ). The stars didn't work. Thanks

Comment: @StuBow75 - you can filter the result with `FIND` or `FINDSTR` (i'll edit the result).If can't compare strings with wild cards.If you know the exact line you need it will be better....

Comment: I did some research on FINDSTR but could only find info on searching with a file. I'll have a go at the new code above and let you know. Once again I really appreciate your help.

Comment: @StuBow75 - with `more`,`findstr`,`sort` and `find` you can use file or a piped stream.